# Trigger pause and continue within a method?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, servlets

How could I "pause" a method in between an execution, and trigger it externally to continue the execution of this method?

The Thread is a servlet, and the `executeAndWait` method is started by a button click.
Now I want to do polling on a `SessionScoped` variable.
If this variable changes its state (eg to true), the polling/waiting method should continue.

I first though about `Observer` pattern. But with this I can just trigger the *execution* of methods. But I need to sleep/wait and trigger the *continue* of a method.

How else could this be done apart from polling to a "global" variable.?

```
class MyThread {

    @Inject
    MyBean bean;

    doExecuteAndWait() {
        //this waits for the var to turn into "true" state
        while(!bean.isVarValid()) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        //continue execution if somevar is set to true externally
    }
}


class MySignal {
    @Inject
    MyBean bean;

    //this triggers the continuation of the method from class above
    toggleVar() {
        bean.setVarValid(true);
    }   
}

@SessionScoped
class MyBean() {
    varValid = false;

    isVarValid() {
        return varValid;
    }

    setVarValid(Boolean status) {
        this.varValid = status;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Initialize it to `1`, call `await()` in `MyThread`, and then call the `countDown()` method from `MySignal` when it should be released.

This way you don't need to keep polling the value of a variable.